# Combining continuous and categorical symbology of a raster in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, symbology, legend

I am trying to replicate a symbology that I created in R using ArcMap 10.5.

I have a raster showing flood depth, with float values ranging from 0.001 to some meters (e.g. 3.8). Anything that is below a threshold (e.g. 1 foot or 30cm), is shown with a continous symbology that starts at 2 inches (5 cm) - that is, anything below that is set as no color / transparent. Above a foot, the color is set as a single fill, which only changes when the maximum depth goes over 2 feet / 60cm. See image below:

[image]

Is it possible to replicate this symbology in ArcMap , without having to generate copies of the original raster and stacking them?

I know gradient bars can be created for continuous data, but I am not sure about the possibility of combining it with a categorical colour after a given threshold.